# Send and recive packet in the LAN with multiple MAC addresses in C#

Tags: c#, proxy, network-programming, lan, mac-address

In our network the bandwidth is assigned to MAC address and if you can get more than one, you can get more bandwidth :)

Is there any application or class in C# that can do this? I already have the HTTP proxy or port mapper to send packets in different IP addresses but because they use the same MAC address it won't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to make your question a bit more clear. Also, the [mac] tag is intended for Apple Macintosh related questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can not. WHile you can CHANGE The MAC address, you will not be able to have more than one on a network card without some pretty heavy lifting driver level wise (and thus definitely not in C#).